# how to initialize SQLite Database variable in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm a beginner in flutter, i want to use SQlite database using sqflite package in my Flutter App, when I declare the `_database` variable with this syntax `static Database _database;` i got a compilation error saying that i must initialize _database, and when i use this syntax `static Database? _database;`, i have a compilation error under `return _database` saying `A value of type 'Database?' can't be returned from the function 'database' because it has a return type of 'Future<Database>'.`
my code is

```
class AnnonceDataBase {

  AnnonceDataBase._();
  static final AnnonceDataBase instance = AnnonceDataBase._();
  static Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await initDB();
    return _database;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this.

```
/// late variable initialization
static late Database _database;
```

Here is more insight why `late` keyword is used.
https://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2021/03/flutter-lazy-instantiation-with-the-late-keyword.html

**Have Fun!**

Answer (score 0):

```
class AppData {
  static const _dbName = '<Database-Name>';
  static const _dbVersion = 1;
  static const _tableName = '<Table-Name>';

  AppData._();

  static final AppData instance = AppData._();

  static Database? _database;

  Future<Database?> get database async {
    if (_database != null) {
      return _database;
    }
    _database = await _initializeDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> _initializeDatabase() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(directory.path, _dbName);
    return await openDatabase(path, version: _dbVersion, onCreate: _onCreate);
  }

  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    try {
      const createQuery = '''
        CREATE TABLE $_tableName(
          /// TODO : <Define table structure here using SQL Query>
        );
        ''';
      await db.execute(createQuery);
    } catch (e) { }
  }
}
```